# format() function in R is not working with same parameters provides different outputs depending on the data used

Tags: r

I have a simple question regarding the "format()" function in R:

I'm trying to format 02 vectors of numbers but the same parameters give different outputs (example):

```
format(c(0.20383715, -6.00074311,  3.00585860,  2.96311003, -3.97974124, -0.07454878), width = 8, digits = 2, nsmall = 2, justify = "right")

format(c(0.3960746, -14.1317006, 7.7651928, 7.8571855, -12.0308722, 1.7247282), width = 8, digits = 2, nsmall = 2, justify = "right")
```

I noticed the 1st output has 3 decimal digits and 2nd has 2 decimal digits.

This is what I got:

```
[1] "   0.204" "  -6.001" "   3.006" "   2.963" "  -3.980" "  -0.075"

[1] "    0.40" "  -14.13" "    7.77" "    7.86" "  -12.03" "    1.72"
```

What am I missing? Thanks for your help.

Kind regards

Answer (score 3):

From the docs for **format**:

**digits**

> How many significant digits are to be used for numeric and complex x. The default, NULL, uses getOption("digits"). This is a suggestion: enough decimal places will be used so that the smallest (in magnitude) number has this many significant digits, and also to satisfy nsmall. (For the interpretation for complex numbers see signif.)

So the reason for the difference is the presence of the number `-0.07454878` in your first vector. In order to show two significant figures, this needs to have three figures after the decimal point, which compels the other numbers in the vector to do the same.

We can show this by removing the final element of the first vector

```r
format(c(0.20383715, -6.00074311,  3.00585860,  2.96311003, -3.97974124), 
       width = 8, digits = 2, nsmall = 2, justify = "right")
#> [1] "    0.20" "   -6.00" "    3.01" "    2.96" "   -3.98"

format(c(0.3960746, -14.1317006, 7.7651928, 7.8571855, 
         -12.0308722, 1.7247282), 
       width = 8, digits = 2, nsmall = 2, justify = "right")
#> [1] "    0.40" "  -14.13" "    7.77" "    7.86" "  -12.03" "    1.72"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Allan this clarifies a lot. I did a workaround by first "rounding" the values on each vector and after that using the format as described and it worked fine. Thank you again!